# capture drag and drop item and send it to flask

Tags: html, flask, drag

I am working on application using flask python from the server side

So in the html side I have drag copy and past events which works very well

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    return ev.target.id
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var nodeCopy = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    nodeCopy.id = "newId"; /* We cannot use the same ID */
    ev.target.appendChild(nodeCopy);
}
```

Then this is the element I want to drag

```
 <div class="row" id=1 draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" >
```

And I dropped it here

```
 <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

My question is how do I send information to flask about the dragged item and the place where he was dropped. 3 days of searching and nada

Comment: No one to help here ? Is it that complicated .???

Comment: I'm also working on something similar and now planning to re-write the whole thing with Flask. What I did is; drag and drop items to let's say divA to divB; then select the content of divB with .innerHTML method in JS and save it to a JS variable. 
Like I said, I'm only considering to write thing in Flask, so I don't know how you can assign the value of a JS variable to a python variable; but that may work.
If you ever managed to get it working, I'd appreciate if you can share the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions from python in the HTML if you specify them;
in app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('html.html', dropped=dropped)

def dropped():
    print('dropped!')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in html.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <style>
            #div1 {
              width: 350px;
              height: 70px;
              padding: 10px;
              border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
          }
          
          function drag(ev) {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
          }
          
          function drop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            {{ dropped() }}
          }</script>

        <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        <br>
        <p id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">hi</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

drag and drop box from [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Set `ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id)` for drag event and
give the id to the element where you want to drop. Then get the id in drop event using `event.target.id` and also get the data using `ev.dataTransfer.getData("text")`.
To send the information to flask make an Ajax call to Flask function with matching route.